# Limit the number of answers per question for users with low reputation

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, answers, limits

Some new users don't know how to edit their own answers, so they post their edits as a second answer to the same question - as people do in forums.

I suggest that we limit the number of answers per question to only one answer for users with low reputation (e.g. less than 50).

For example see my question [Could not find adb.exe - after upgrade to Android SDK 2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375175/could-not-find-adb-exe-after-upgrade-to-android-sdk-2-3), it has five answers. And four of them are from users with reputation 1 that have posted two answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Won't they get a pop-up, which they'd have to ignore?

[image]

Seems OK to me to (try to) educate them that way.  I've seen the related issue where new users post updates to their *questions* as answers more often.

Comment: Maybe a pop-in/lightbox could give some better choices than the browser's Cancel and OK. (As an aside, folks answering their own question are ignoring two warnings too, the button being labeled "Answer Your Question", and the dialog http://i.imgur.com/2WpJc.png)

Comment: @Arjan Well if nobody else answers the question, its sure ok to provide an answer at least approximately, compiled from the comments on the question, isnt it?

Comment: @Sebastian, it surely is. I was just commenting to Martin's *related issue where new users post updates to their questions as answers more often,* which however has a similar popup. I *could* read this answer as "the popup should be sufficient to stop multiple answers", while at the same time it apparently is not sufficient for the related issue?

Comment: @Arjan - I don't think the multiple answers do much harm, but an answer which should _really_ be an update to a question tends to result in a mess.

Comment: @Arjan, well I get your point, if people already ignore a popup warning, they just go ahead and do post edits as answers anyways. I just don't see how there is any good means to educate users more about a more appropriate way to deal with it, here on SO nobody can be forced to comply with any rule basically